# Example of CRC manual calculationfor CAN 2.0 B

Tags: crc, can-bus

I have seem the CRC calculation polynomial for CAN 2.0B, but I have no examples to actually make sure I understood how to calculate it.

```
X15 + X14 + X10 + X8 + X7 + X4 + X3 + 1
```

I would really appreciate seeing a step by step calculation for such a CRC.

Answer (score 0):

The CAN 2.0 document says exactly how to do it:

```
CRC_RG = 0 //initialize shift register
REPEAT
    CRCNXT = NXTBIT EXOR CRC_RG(14)
    CRC_RG(14:1) = CRC_RG(13:0) //shift left by...
    CRC_RG(0) = 0 //...one position
    IF CRCNXT THEN
        CRC_RG(14:0) = CRC_RG(14:0) EXOR (4599 hex)
    ENDIF
UNTIL (CRC SEQUENCE starts or there is an ERROR condition)
```

Note that 4599 in hex is the polynomial, i.e. the bits 14, 10, 8, 7, 4, 3, and 0 are set.  (The 15 bit position is what is pulled off after the shift.)

You can find an example [here](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat-bits.15) to verify that you're doing it right.  This CRC applied to the ASCII string of digits (nine bytes) `123456789` is `0x059e`.

Comment: Could you show me a practical example so I can manually calculate it?